# VirtualBox linked clones - does updating parent automatically update children?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have tried linked clones, immutable, multiattach everything but I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

I have the following scenario -

(parent) - base install, updates as of Monday

(child 1) - linked clone from parent, created on Tuesday, devel work happening on this throughout the week

(child 2) - linked clone from parent, created on Wednesday, devel work happening on tihs through the week

on Friday, there's an update available, so (parent) gets updated.

Now, on Monday, can (child 1) and (child2) see the update somehow? (assuming they haven't individually updated themselves?

If (child1) or (child2) did update themselves on Friday right before (parent) updated once (parent) updates itself, does the merge happen cleanly?

(I am thinking of handling VMs the way SVN trunk and branches work for instance. After creating a linked clone, can the changes made in the parent be "pulled" in to the linked clones, or is this not doable at all?)

(NOTE: Is this doable in any hypervisor platform?)

Answer (score 1):

Linked clones use snapshot of the parent VMs disk, changes in the parent are written to a delta disk after the cloning. So if you change something in the parent after the cloning, the changes will not be available to the linked clones.
This is very similar to [snapshots in vmware](https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1015180)

VMware workstation documents contain a good explanation of the differences between full and linked clones, I suggest you read it also.

> A linked clone is made from a snapshot of the parent.

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_clone_typeofclone.html